# Open file with JNLP / Webstart

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to pass a file path as parameter on Windows to be opened in a `JAVA` `JNLP`. Starting with the original JAR file, i created a wrapper `BATCH` file `runMyJar.bat`:

```
java -jar "%~dp0MyJarFile.jar" %*
```

Then i configure windows to open all `*.test` files with my `runMyJar.bat` which works fine: When i double click any `*.test` file it run `MyJarFile.jar` and passes the path of the `*.test` file.

Now i want to do the same with a `JNLP` to deploy my `JAR` with webstart but to offer Windows `Open with...` for my application. So my idea is to offer a `BATCH` wrapper file again:

```
javaws -open %1 "http://urlToMyJNLP"
```

Unfortunately thats not working. When starting this wrapper batch with a file i'm just receiving a null object in my `static void main` method for the parameter `args`.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
Based on the answer i summarized it [here](http://open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=65).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that due to security updates to Java your method of passing arugments to javaws no longer works.

Have you tried using the "association" tag in jnlp instead to achieve your goal?

Another option is to pass arguments using properties and then read that property in your java code:

```
javaws -J-Djnlp.arg0=%1 thefile.jnlp
```

Comment: Yes the arguments will stil be null. What I suggested is just a workaround to use properties instead of arguments. You need to use System.getProperty("jnlp.arg0") inside your java program to retrieve the value of arg0.

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works perfect! Not the best argument of Oracle to disallow parameters for security reason to pass to signed jars anyway....